# Product over empty set

Tags: arithmetic, products

Assuming some kind of function $f(x)$, what is the value of $\prod\limits_{x \in \varnothing}f(x)$? https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Empty_product suggests that it is equal to $1$ but I wasn't sure if it ever depends on what it's multiplying and if it holds true for all cases.

Comment: It is the multiplicative identity for whatever specific type of multiplication it is.  It could be the multiplicative identity of the real numbers, it could be the multiplicative identity of the set of $n\times n$ matrices, etc...